# Algorithm to generate possible combinations of players from all players of team

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, backtracking

Let's say I have 3 postions `[goalkeeper, midfilder, striker]` and 6 players

```
[{"name":A, "position":goalkeeper, "salary":300, "rating" : 9},
{"name": B, "position":goalkeeper, "salary":200, "rating" : 8 },
{"name": C, "position":midfilder, "salary":400 , "rating" : 9},
{"name": D, "position":midfilder, "salary":300 , "rating" : 7},
{"name": E, "position":striker, "salary":400, "rating" : 9 },
{"name": F, "position":striker, "salary":200 ,"rating" : 7}]
```

Now I need to build all possible combinations of teams with all 3 positions from 6 player with maximum ratings and within my total budget salary of 1100.

Output should be like this

```
[{ "team" : [A,C,E],
    "total_salary" : 1100,
    "total_rating" : 27
  },
 { "team" : [B,C,E],
    "total_salary" : 1000,
    "total_rating" : 26
  },
  { "team" : [A,D,E],
    "total_salary" : 1000,
    "total_rating" : 25
  }.. all possible combinations. Players will be choosed based on position. there can't be 2 players with same position.]
```

I found bit of solution here : [combinations of players for a team in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923218/combinations-of-players-for-a-team-in-c)
But it seems in C but seems not feasible and I need it in JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: show your code attempt

Comment: Have you tried writing anything yourself yet? SO isn't here to write your whole script for you - if you run into a specific problem, please ask it and we can help debug.

Comment: Does it sounds only to me or it is a knapsack problem described here ?

Comment: There are only eight possibilities: 2 choices for goal, 2 for mid, 2 for striker gives 2*2*2 = 8 possibilities. And none of them are over budget, since choosing the most expensive player at each position gives a total salary of 1100.

Comment: Yeah Its just scenario. I can have hundreds of players with different positions. I am working on code, will add it soon here.